Update column value in multiple table
I have multiple tables in PostGIS all table have column 'updated_by' and I want to update the value of column with value 'Paul' in all tables using For Loop.

Can you help?

Add the code as text, not a screenshot of it. What is the problem, do you get errors?

PostgreSQL does not suport dynamic object injection (here the table name) in SQL directly. You will have to construct and EXECUTE a pre-formatted SQL string literal - see Dynamic SQL and e.g. FORMAT.

Here's a demo.
